# Laravel 5.2 openshift

Tags: laravel, deployment, openshift

I am having trouble deploying an example laravel 5.2 application to openshift.
I've found this [quickstart](https://github.com/lucho2d7/openshift-quickstart-laravel5.2) on github and tried the manual installation that is listed below.

```
rhc app create laravelapp php-5.4 mysql-5.5 --from-code=https://github.com/lucho2d7/openshift-quickstart-laravel5.2
```

But I get an error claiming that this quickstart needs a php 5.6 version. Then I found this [php 5.6 cartridge](https://github.com/boekkooi/openshift-cartridge-php), but I don't know how to install this cartridge before creating the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing php 5.6 in the openshift gears could be really easy.

Follow the steps in this repo :
https://github.com/boekkooi/openshift-cartridge-php/

or this one ：

https://djordjekovacevic.com/articles/run-laravel-5.1-on-openshift

Hope this could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, the second link did the trick and for the DB migrations I helped with this [guide](http://www.rownet.co.uk/laravel-plus-openshift-equals-awesome-part-2/)

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for sharing the guide of DB migration. It will be helpful for Laravel deployment.